# Generate all possible combinations in Python

Tags: python, pandas, combinations

```
     Choice1   Choice2   Choice3
A       1         5         9
B       2         6         10
C       3         7         11
D       4         8         12
```

How can i generate all possible combinations that include one choice for each row in python?

Comment: Dunno if you need a pandas-specific solution, but without pandas, that'd be `itertools.product(*rowlist)`.

Comment: Looking at your column names, I get the feeling that there might be a better way to do what you want. What is your ultimate goal here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this to get the Cartesian product.

```
import itertools

rowlists = [[1,5,9],[2,6,10],[3,7,11],[4,8,12]]
for combination in itertools.product(*rowlists):
    print combination
```